# CouchDB is that possible i can set up the database_dir to a network location

Tags: couchdb

I am new to couchdb, i have been testing and playing with it for a little bit on my local disk. I am planning to move onto bigger data (200,300 GB). However, i don't have that much space on my local disk, but my company has a NAS (Isilon) that has a couple of TB space I could use. I don't know if it's possible for CouchDB to save all the data on the network disk (such as by UNC path).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could mount a network location ans use it. However you want to be careful what you wish for: you add another potential breaking point and a network latency. Databases, and couchdb is no exception, are by nature I/O intensive, so you might not get the performance you are looking for.
CouchDB runs on many platforms (we just made it run on a Rasberry PI), so you actually might be able to run it directly on the NAS. If [IsilionOS](http://www.emc.com/storage/isilon/isilon-onefs-operating-system.htm) is Linux based it could work.